# Bootstrap 5 navbar button collapse doesn't work

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-5

I have tried to follow tutorial about bootstrap https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KoUzchViH0&t=1457s  i think i did everything like in tutorial but it's doesn't work :c. (Collapse button is showing but when i press it nothing happens. I take template from bootstrap website so i think every js and css should be attached.

(test.css is blank, {% load static %} is from django framework)

```html
{% load static %}
<head>
    <title>Strona testowa / Hobbyist.pl</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- ... -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/test.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-md">
            <!-- m (margin) l/r/t/b (x=l+r, y=t+b) - wartość ekranu - wartość marginu d (diaplay) - wartość ekranu - wartość displayu -->
            <h1 class="navbar-brand"><img src="{% static 'logo.png' %}" style="width:30;height:30;" class="mr-2 d-none d-md-inline-block align-bottom "></img>Navbar</h1>
            <!-- order first - toggler przed logo -->
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                TESTT
            </div>
            
            
        </nav>
    </header>
    
    <!-- predefiniowany container bootstrapa -->
    <!-- maksymalna wielkość (dalej sie nie "rozlewa") -->
    <div class="container">
    <!-- wiersz gx-() gy-() odstępy między elementami-->
        <div class="row gy-0">
                <!-- domyślnie pionowo col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3 (12 kolumn zajmij 4 w widoku small (576px-767px) możliwości: xs sm md lg xl -->
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 offset-md-1">
                    <!-- img-fluid = style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" -->
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://antykorupcja.gov.pl/dokumenty/zalaczniki/4/4-16841.jpg"></img>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vestibulum ullamcorper quam, vel auctor odio sagittis quis. Fusce auctor tristique odio, sed molestie purus finibus et. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc porttitor leo ante, at egestas libero tempor iaculis. Donec ligula diam, dignissim et arcu at, sodales mollis mauris. Proin quis magna tellus. Morbi posuere faucibus massa, in molestie sem commodo at. Vivamus iaculis neque erat, eu vulputate mauris cursus sit amet. Praesent vitae justo neque. Nunc et elementum tortor.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.wykop.pl/cdn/c3201142/comment_HRdOdvKNI54mPFZ37Ilw3L49tj2NfKGE.jpg"></img>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vestibulum ullamcorper quam, vel auctor odio sagittis quis. Fusce auctor tristique odio, sed molestie purus finibus et. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc porttitor leo ante, at egestas libero tempor iaculis. Donec ligula diam, dignissim et arcu at, sodales mollis mauris. Proin quis magna tellus. Morbi posuere faucibus massa, in molestie sem commodo at. Vivamus iaculis neque erat, eu vulputate mauris cursus sit amet. Praesent vitae justo neque. Nunc et elementum tortor.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.crazynauka.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/pingwin3.jpg"></img>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vestibulum ullamcorper quam, vel auctor odio sagittis quis. Fusce auctor tristique odio, sed molestie purus finibus et. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc porttitor leo ante, at egestas libero tempor iaculis. Donec ligula diam, dignissim et arcu at, sodales mollis mauris. Proin quis magna tellus. Morbi posuere faucibus massa, in molestie sem commodo at. Vivamus iaculis neque erat, eu vulputate mauris cursus sit amet. Praesent vitae justo neque. Nunc et elementum tortor.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://antykorupcja.gov.pl/dokumenty/zalaczniki/4/4-16841.jpg"></img>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vestibulum ullamcorper quam, vel auctor odio sagittis quis. Fusce auctor tristique odio, sed molestie purus finibus et. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc porttitor leo ante, at egestas libero tempor iaculis. Donec ligula diam, dignissim et arcu at, sodales mollis mauris. Proin quis magna tellus. Morbi posuere faucibus massa, in molestie sem commodo at. Vivamus iaculis neque erat, eu vulputate mauris cursus sit amet. Praesent vitae justo neque. Nunc et elementum tortor.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://antykorupcja.gov.pl/dokumenty/zalaczniki/4/4-16841.jpg"></img>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vestibulum ullamcorper quam, vel auctor odio sagittis quis. Fusce auctor tristique odio, sed molestie purus finibus et. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc porttitor leo ante, at egestas libero tempor iaculis. Donec ligula diam, dignissim et arcu at, sodales mollis mauris. Proin quis magna tellus. Morbi posuere faucibus massa, in molestie sem commodo at. Vivamus iaculis neque erat, eu vulputate mauris cursus sit amet. Praesent vitae justo neque. Nunc et elementum tortor.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://antykorupcja.gov.pl/dokumenty/zalaczniki/4/4-16841.jpg"></img>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vestibulum ullamcorper quam, vel auctor odio sagittis quis. Fusce auctor tristique odio, sed molestie purus finibus et. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc porttitor leo ante, at egestas libero tempor iaculis. Donec ligula diam, dignissim et arcu at, sodales mollis mauris. Proin quis magna tellus. Morbi posuere faucibus massa, in molestie sem commodo at. Vivamus iaculis neque erat, eu vulputate mauris cursus sit amet. Praesent vitae justo neque. Nunc et elementum tortor.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://antykorupcja.gov.pl/dokumenty/zalaczniki/4/4-16841.jpg"></img>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vestibulum ullamcorper quam, vel auctor odio sagittis quis. Fusce auctor tristique odio, sed molestie purus finibus et. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc porttitor leo ante, at egestas libero tempor iaculis. Donec ligula diam, dignissim et arcu at, sodales mollis mauris. Proin quis magna tellus. Morbi posuere faucibus massa, in molestie sem commodo at. Vivamus iaculis neque erat, eu vulputate mauris cursus sit amet. Praesent vitae justo neque. Nunc et elementum tortor.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://antykorupcja.gov.pl/dokumenty/zalaczniki/4/4-16841.jpg"></img>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vestibulum ullamcorper quam, vel auctor odio sagittis quis. Fusce auctor tristique odio, sed molestie purus finibus et. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc porttitor leo ante, at egestas libero tempor iaculis. Donec ligula diam, dignissim et arcu at, sodales mollis mauris. Proin quis magna tellus. Morbi posuere faucibus massa, in molestie sem commodo at. Vivamus iaculis neque erat, eu vulputate mauris cursus sit amet. Praesent vitae justo neque. Nunc et elementum tortor.</p>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- rozlewa sie w nieskonczonsc 
    <div class="container-fluid">
        
    </div> -->
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- ... -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing these two attributes in your button tag : `data-bs-toggle="collapse" & data-bs-target="#test"`. Also, add the "id" attribute in the div tag which you want to expand on button click. So, your code be like:

```html
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#test">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="test">
    TESTT
</div>
```

**Remember**: - The `data-bs-target` attribute indicated which element to be collapse / expand on button click. So the value of the "id" attribute and the value of the "data-bs-target" attribute will be the same. In this case, I have takes "test" as a value.